# White line In Google Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit, line

I am designing a website for a friend and when she visits the website she insists that she is seeing a white line at the top of the page. I have been trying to reproduce this white line and I have been unsuccessful. I have looked at the background image and there is no white lines on the border and I have also changing the zoom and screen resolution. The weird thing is that we are both using the latest version of Google Chrome (19.0.1084.56 m). Any ideas?

Comment: are you both running on the same OS? have you both cleared your cache?

Comment: We are both running Windows 7. I will ask her again to try clearing the cache

Comment: Also can't see it (OSX). Maybe ask your friend to take a screenshot - might help clarify exactly what this white line looks like.

Comment: and screenshot of right-click inspect element

Comment: I can try and ask her for a screenshot of the page but not sure about inspect element

Comment: Also ask if she has any extensions which affect web pages.

Comment: btw in chrome 19.0.1084.56 m I cannot find a white line ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the firebug (lite) extension her chrome browser and "inspect" the white line (select inspector, check the code causing the white line). This will bring you much nearer to the solution, as this shows you exactly WHERE in the markup the white line is created.

Comment: Why not just use the built in web inspector?